Solving the recurrence $a_1 = 1$, $a_n = n + a_{n-1} (n + 1)$
To solve a problem I had to find a formula for the following recurrence relation.
$a_1 = 1$
$a_n = n + a_{n-1} (n + 1)$
After some time I realized the pattern it was following. I realized that
$a_n = (n + 1)! - 1$
I did the proof by induction, but I was wondered, is there any way to prove this without using induction and without “guessing” the formula?
I would appreciate it if you could share any ideas you may have.

Do you know the generating function?

Induction is certainly the simplest way.

Try divide both sides by $(n+1)!$, you may see a difference in sequence

Sometimes it is convenient to define an auxiliary recursion. In this case, you may define $b_n=a_n+1$ with $b_0=1$ for convenience. The recursion for $(b_n)$ is the following:
$$ b_0=1,\quad b_{n}=a_{n}+1=n+1+a_{n-1}(n+1)=b_{n-1}(n+1),\quad n\ge 1.$$
You may easily identify that this is the recursion of the factorial function, namely, $b_n=(n+1)!$ and thus $a_n=(n+1)!-1$.

One may also consider using the approach outline here to solve the recurrence for $b_n$.

Let $a_0=0$ and $f(x)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_nx^n$ be the generating function, then \begin{align} \sum_{n=1}^\infty a_nx^n=\sum_{n=1}^\infty nx^n+\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_{n-1}(n+1)x^n\end{align}
For $\sum_{n=1}^\infty nx^n$, we have $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty x^n=\frac{x}{1-x}\implies x\sum_{n=1}^\infty nx^{n-1}=x\left( \frac{x}{1-x}\right)'=\frac{x}{(1-x)^2}$$
For $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_{n-1}(n+1)x^n$, we have $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_{n-1}(n+1)x^n=\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_{n-1}nx^n+xf(x)$$
Again, $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_{n-1}x^n=xf(x)\implies \sum_{n=1}^\infty a_{n-1}nx^n=xf(x)+x^2f'(x)$$
Thus, $$f(x)=\frac{x}{(1-x)^2}+2xf(x)+x^2f'(x)\implies f'(x)+\frac{1-2x}{x^2}f(x)=\frac{1}{(1-x)^2x}$$
Although we can solve the ODE to get $f(x)$ and then use Taylor expansion to get $a_n$, this method does not work well in this situation.

Maybe try an exponential generating function instead.
